# I set debug mode on in Flask but it is being showed as "off" in PyCharm console

Tags: flask, pycharm

As I express in the above section, I couldn't set debug mode even I type "app.run(debug=True)" in PyCharm.Take a look at console ,it says "Debug mode : off"

[image: Console photo]

[image: whole code]

Answer (score 1):

Weel , you should click on the wrench button which is in the second row of first vertical column,I attached a photo of it,and enable the flask_debug form on- its photo also was attched -. I even didn't know this part's exixtence and its relation about app , I just found it by chance so I wanted to share it, I hope I helped you a little bit and made things easier.

[image: here wrech button]

[image: here flask_debug form to enable it]

Answer (score 1):

The environment variable for running in debug mode should be set to 1 (ie True):

```
>>> FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Or, set the development mode explicitly, which also starts the debugger and also enables hot-reloading:

```
>>> FLASK_ENV=development
```

Comment: Thx for your answer , I already declared that -Sorry, I just forgot to add my whole code screen shot and that's why you didn't see what I typed ,sorry again I'm new in this community- by typing  "app.run(debug=True) " as you see in the second photo -I just added it as I said - and ofcourse your options are also valid for the solution .+

Comment: +My point here is the app was still running in "debug-mode=off" becasue of a PyCharm feature (or problem in my case cause I didn't know about it) despite my code  and I couldn't find any question tag or pratic solution about it and discovered the solution by chance as I expressed that's why I wanted to let others who may have the same problem in PyCharm to know about it and save their time .

Comment: To summarize we can't fix it just typing code we also should "enable" the debug-mode form  if we are using PyCharm.

Comment: This worked for me.  The checkbox didn't seem to have any effect, but it's working with the checkbox checked AND the environment variable set to FLASK_DEBUG=1

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've handled this issue with pyCharm pro 2022.

1). Set env:

```
FLASK_DEBUG = 1

FLASK_ENV = "development"  # it will be deprecated since Flask 2.3
```

2). Do not use pyCharm's Flask IDE template, use regular Python project instead with a setting below:
[image: pyCharm settings to make Flask debug mode active]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I tried to fix it using your piece of advice. It didn't work, though.
[configuration settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noYo6.png)
[flask-running-on-pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spCDy.png)

So, I opened a terminal(*Powershell*) on *Pycharm* 2022.2 Build #PY-222.3345.131 and proceed to write this.
I have to say I was using *Pipenv* and *Python 3.8.13*

```
$env:FLASK_ENV = "development"
$env:FLASK_DEBUG = 1
python -m flask run
```

[flask-on-powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chl0W.png)